# I deleted my GUI, and nothing happens when i reinstall it!

Tags: apt, upgrade, system-installation, gui

Now whenever i open my laptop, it shows up without the GUI, i assume i somehow did something to delete it, but now whenever i go back to reinstall my `ubuntu-desktop` it tells me this `Reading package lists… Dine Building dependency tree Reading state information ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.450.2) 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 326 not upgraded.`.
and then i run reboot, still a blank screen, i go to press ctrl f7, nothing, but then if i press ctrl f1, back to the terminal. here is the output of df -h for popey ! [df -h](https://file.garden/ZG0r8GLYvB6VkKBZ/B177F836-5FE2-40F7-8151-89BBAB280644.jpeg)

Comment: Edit: It turns out when i press ctrl+f7, it brings me to a terminal like screen, and it says ```/dev/mmcblk0p2: clean, 320672/3784704 files, 14396406/15136256 blocks```.

Comment: Can you login to the terminal prompt and run the command `startx` ?

Comment: Please post the output of `systemctl status gdm.service`

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` - the caret (`^`) is important.

Comment: this was the correct awnser, but it gives me this error ```E: You dont have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.```

Comment: Your disk is full? If it's all one partition, maybe delete some things from your home directory. What's the output of `df -h` (add this to your question)

Comment: This is a 64GB SD card? Looks like you're running out of space due to all the media or whatever is on your "doombox". Might need a bigger SD card.